# Speed up internet by multiple connections

Tags: networking, internet, network-bonding

I had made research about increasing internet speed by connection on multiple source.
And i find out that ubuntu support it already.
I had connect two phone; iPhone with cable and Samsung with WiFi. and my download speed was increased (not downloading single file just when using internet for opening web pages etc.)
Now I want to connect; one or two 3G mobil modem, and one phone with cable, but when I connect 3G modem and phone I only can use one connection at the time and there is no any increase in speed.
I had read about bonding, but I dont know would it solve my problem.
I just need more bandwidth for surfing web not for download.

Thank you all for your help

Comment: I really dont undestand downvoting without comment! who you are and what is the reason for downvote? if you have something to say, write comment so I can improve question.